# Using provided scope for javaee-api version 6 causes wsgen to fail in Maven

Tags: maven, java-ee-6, wsgen

I use wsgen from the jaxws-maven-plugin to generate web service artifacts from my @WebService java class (start from Java).  My web service class injects an @EJB.  I've included the javaee-api version 6 as a dependency.

Everything was working fine until I changed the javaee-api scope to provided.  If I don't do this the javaee-api.jar gets included in my .war file, which I do not want.

Using provided shouldn't cause a compile failure.  [Someone else noticed this](http://old.nabble.com/-Issue-837--New---wsgen-having-problems-with-javax.ejb.%2a-annotations-td27796924.html) but not in maven.

Here's the relevant section from my pom.xml.

Thanks.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.12</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsgen</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <sei>com.co.report.reports.ws.server.ReportService</sei>
            <genWsdl>false</genWsdl>
            <keep>true</keep>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <!--   Setting <scope>provided</scope> causes compile failure -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add javax:javaee-api:6.0 as a dependency to the plugin itself.

You can add a `<dependencies>` tag inside a `<plugin>` tag.

Please see the [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin) for more detail.

Comment: That solved it.  Still not clear why it wouldn't compile with <scope>provided</scope> in the pom dependencies, though.

Comment: When I do that I have problem with javax.mail package (It's not included)